# How to exclude a pattern like this?

Tags: regex, codeigniter

I've a pattern like this. The pattern is for Chinese characters compatible.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '|^[a-z 0-9~%\.\:_\+\- \x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}]+$|iu';
```

Now I need to filter out those characters not permitted, but it's not working as below.

```
$clean_str = preg_replace('#[^'.$CI->config->item('permitted_uri_chars').']#i', '', $str);
```

Any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permitted only -

```
$clean_str = preg_replace( '/[^a-z 0-9~%.:_+\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}-]+/iu', '', $str) ;
```